# If there turns out to be matter with negative mass, would there also be antimatter with negative mass?

Tags: mass, antimatter

I just heard of the concept of [**negative mass**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_mass).

Googling led me to see that the concept of negative mass is often contrasted with **[antimatter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antimatter)**.

This made me to wonder whether there would then also be a fourth category of [**exotic matter**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exotic_matter) being **antimatter with negative mass**. Of this I can find no mention.

If it turns out that we have **1)** normal matter **2)** antimatter and **3)** normal matter with negative mass, would that imply that we would also have **4)** antimatter with negative mass?

Answer (score 1):

yes absolutely. just recently it was proven that the universe is indeed symmetric. so if there was exotic matter, which is also called mirror matter and negative matter then it will also require a antimatter partner too. this results in four types of matter, and doubles the diversity of matter observed. hawking radiation requires negative mass so a antimatter version of negative mass is extremely likely. in fact light may be a source for the new particles as a composite particle of opposing masses and charges which cancel to zero. the theory must explain all the other effects of light found so far to be a candidate theory. this might just solve the problem of where these other types of matter went so that the universe can exist in the current form by giving the idea that the universe may have spit apart into layers and sections in stages moments after inflation.

Comment: Source(s) needed.